# Identical instance of longtabu

Tags: tables, environments

Defining a class file, I would like to define a new environment, which is essentially a `longtabu`. The `longtabu` is defined to have a variable width left column, which I would like to be identical in all instances of the environment, although it is the second instance that will determine the width of that column.

The class file

```
    \newenvironment{listazo}{
    \begin{longtabu} to \textwidth{X[-1l]X}}
    {\end{longtabu}}
```

The tex file

```
    \section*{First}
    \begin{listazo}

    ... stuff ...

    \end{listazo}

    \section*{Second}
    \begin{listazo}

    ... stuff ...

    \end{listazo}
```

At the moment each instance of the environment sets the width of the first column differently.  How can I make them all use the same column widths, moreover those of the second instance of the environment?

Comment: welcome to tex.sx. It always helps anyone testing a possible answer if you make your question have a _complete_ (small) document that shows the issue rather than a fragment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tabu is just using longtable internals here so you could do

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable,tabu}



    \newenvironment{listazo}{
    \begin{longtabu} to \textwidth{X[-1l]X}}
    {\end{longtabu}}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
{\let\ifhmode\iftrue
\xdef\tmp{\csname LT@ii\endcsname}%
\xdef\tmp{\expandafter\@gobble\tmp}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

The tex file

    \section*{First}
    \begin{listazo}

   aaaaaa & bbbb bbb bbb bbb bb bb bb\\\tmp\kill
    \end{listazo}

    \section*{Second}
    \begin{listazo}

   aaaaaa aa a a a a a a a a & bbbb bbb bbb bbb bb bb bb  bb b b b b b b \\
   aaaaaa aa a a a a a a a a   aaaaaa aa a a a a a a a a & 
bbbb bbb bbb bbb bb bb bb  bb b b b b b b 
bbbb bbb bbb bbb bb bb bb  bb b b b b b b 



    \end{listazo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow! There is no way I could have worked that out myself.  Thanks.

Comment: Just one more thing - this doesn't work exactly if I set the alignment of the first column to right-aligned.  The second table is correct, but the first does not respect the alignment.

Comment: @Jonathan seems unlikely that `\kill` line affects alignment, I don't use tabu myself, what happens if you put the two tables together as a single table, does that get the alignment right? feel free to ask a new question (with a complete example that shows the problem this time:-)

Comment: I have just realised that the designation `\textwidth{X[-1l]X}}` is redundant in my case, since the text in the first column will always be short.
Hence `\textwidth{lX}}` will be just fine. In which case, converting 'l' to 'r' to change the alignment seems to work correctly if `\hfill` is added to the start of the first column.

Comment: @Jonathan or of course you could save tex a lot of work and just use something like \begin{longtable}[r]{rp{.75\textwidth}} with longtable and not use tabu X at all and preservation of teh alignment is automatic.