# Retain longtabu settings throughout document

Tags: tables

This question is a continuation of this previous one [Identical instance of longtabu](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124586/identical-instance-of-longtabu)

I would like to create an environment this is a `longtabu` where the column widths determined for the second instance of the environment are used throughout the document.  David Carlisle gave a great solution in the previous post -

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable,tabu}

\newenvironment{listazo}{
\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth{X[-1l]X}}
{\end{longtabu}}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
{\let\ifhmode\iftrue
\xdef\tmp{\csname LT@ii\endcsname}%
\xdef\tmp{\expandafter\@gobble\tmp}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\section*{First}
\begin{listazo}

  side note1 & here is the text and details\\\tmp\kill

\end{listazo}

\section*{Second}
\begin{listazo}

  side note 2 & more text and details over here - bbbbbbbb bbbbb bbbb bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb\\
  longer side note & bbbb bbb bbb bbb bb bb bb  bb b b b b b b bbbb bbb bbb bbb bb bb bb  bb b b b b b b 

\end{listazo}

\end{document}
```

Which comes out just like I want.  However, if I change the alignment setting of the `longtabu` to be right-aligned, like this -

```
\newenvironment{listazo}{
\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth{X[-1r]X}}  % changed 'l' for 'r' here
{\end{longtabu}}
```

The first column of the first table is still left-aligned like this (note: adding \hfill did not fix it)

[image]

Any help greatly appreciated - I'm out of my depth here.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Ohh, slightly more fragile this time but

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable,tabu}

\newenvironment{listazo}{
\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth{X[-1r]X}}
{\end{longtabu}}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
{\let\ifhmode\iftrue\def\omit{\noindent}%
\xdef\tmp{\csname LT@ii\endcsname}%
\xdef\tmp{\expandafter\@gobble\tmp}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}



\section*{First}
\begin{listazo}
  side note1 & here is the text and details\\\tmp\kill
\end{listazo}

\section*{Second}
\begin{listazo}

  side note 2 & more text and details over here - bbbbbbbb bbbbb bbbb bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb\\
  longer side note & bbbb bbb bbb bbb bb bb bb  bb b b b b b b bbbb bbb bbb bbb bb bb bb  bb b b b b b b 

\end{listazo}


\section*{test}
\begin{listazo}

  side note1 & here is the text and details\\

  side note 2 & more text and details over here - bbbbbbbb bbbbb bbbb bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb\\
  longer side note & bbbb bbb bbb bbb bb bb bb  bb b b b b b b bbbb bbb bbb bbb bb bb bb  bb b b b b b b 

\end{listazo}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why, but the columns of the first section are now not the same as the following examples, but the alignment is correct. :S